# Looking for an alternative to "I hope that...", "I'm hopeful that..." and all the similar expressions

Tags: synonyms

Whenever I say "I hope you...", or "I hope that...", or "I'm hopeful you will...", it sounds so hollow. In part, I think, because it sounds cliche (to me anyway), but also because I can't think of a single statement to substitute for it.

I've looked up as many "Hope"-related questions on this site. I'm hoping (Arrrgh) to get a suggestion for an alternative.

Comment: Hopefully, "May you..." doesn't sound too cliche.

Comment: What do you want to sound like? I'm not sure we can help with hollowness here.

Comment: If you don't want to use a cliché, then simply do not use it. If you replace it with a synonym, *you are still using the cliché*, just with some lipstick on. (And that's the best-case scenario; more likely, you'll be putting mud on it rather than lipstick.) Either you *do* hope — then there is nothing wrong with stating just that —, or you do not hope — then just do not state anything to that extent and be done.

Answer (score 4):

I **trust** that you will ...

**Trust** is a good alternative as it either:

- places the imperative on the person being addressed (*I hope you will answer my question* vs *I trust you will answer my question*), or
- indicates a level of respect for the person being addressed. (*I hope you will be able to suggest an alternative* vs *I trust you will be able to suggest an alternative*)

Comment: Actually, I think that increasingly over recent decades, *"I trust you will do X"* is more likely to be used as a disdainful/pompous way of implying *"It **would be ridiculous** for you **not** to do X"*.

Comment: It certainly can have that usage as well, especially if the emphasis is placed on the word **trust** when spoken. In written English it would depend on the context.

Answer (score 1):

I always find: "Looking forward to... All good things, Yours, Greg." 
Quite simple & one can vary it all sorts of ways. Here is hoping that helps ! Ouch...

Comment: This (whatever its merits) seems to be a suggestion for closing an email, which is not actually what OP is asking for.